# How to model a turtle's shell starting from a circle/ using a circle?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm trying to model a turtle's shell. I wonder how I can start with a Circle and create the shell?

Comment: You may start with a circle with 10 vertices, model a flat patern, then inset some faces and use a proportional editing to make a plane look like a shell. It's quite simple. Give me 5 mins and I'll show you how to do it fast :).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where can I see the vertices?  I wait.

Comment: I see "Vector  X,Y,Z......

Comment: I see "Vertices Data" in Edit mode, right side "n"

Comment: Meri, your question isn't clear. Could you please change the question to something like: "How to model a turtle's shell starting from a circle/ using a circle?", so people who'll be searching for an answer in future may easily find it..

Answer (score 34):

Add a ***Circle*** and set its vertices number to ***10***. 
[image]

Scale and rotate it to fit the picture using *snapping tool* (click on a magnet icon and set its type to *Increment*). Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while rotating to do it precisely. [In this case i rotated a circle 18 degress]. Being in *Edit Mode* select the whole circle (<kbd>A</kbd>), then pres <kbd>W</kbd>*-->Subdivide*.
[image]

Delete one half of a mesh and give it a *Mirror Modifier*. Extrude the vertices to fit the reference image. 
[image]

Apply a *Mirror Modifier* and then add a *Subsurf Modifier*. Select the outer edges and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (with a cursor snapped to an origin point) to make them spherical.
[image]

Now set the pivot point to *Individual Origins*. Select the faces as pictured below, then press <kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>I</kbd> again to inset the individual faces. Repeat the process with other faces.
[image]

Select the edges as pictured below, press <kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd>. Select all edges and sharpen them using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut.
[image]

Give it a proper shape using ***Lattice Modifier*** and *proportional editing*. Give it some thickness using ***Solidify Modifier***.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is your best answer yet. Well done. An extra plus for using the lattice modifier.

Comment: This is super cool! Is there are general rule for when you should use a lattice modifier versus when you should model with proportional editing?

Comment: @ajwood I think there are no rules :). It depends on a task. I prefer using lattice modifier with proportional editing enabled at the same time :). This explosive mix gives you an ultimate control over mesh transformation.